# Combining two scripts into one code for csv file data verification

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone currently I have two scripts that I would like to combine into 1 code. The first script finds missing time stamps from a set of data and fills in a blank row with NaN values then saves to an output file.  The second script compares different rows in a set of data and creates a new column with True/False values based on the test condition.

If I run each script as a function then call both with another function I would get two separate output files.  How can I make this run with only 1 saved output file?

**First Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data5.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
df = df.resample('1min').mean()
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
df.to_csv("output.csv", na_rep='NaN')
```

**Second Code**

```
with open('data5.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = [row.split(',') for row in f]
    rows = [[cell.strip() for cell in row if cell] for row in rows]

def isValidRow(row):
    return float(row[5]) <= 900 or all(float(val) > 7 for val in row[1:4])

header, rows = rows[0], rows[1:]
validRows = list(map(isValidRow, rows))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(header + ['IsValid']) + '\n')
    for row, valid in zip(rows, validRows):
        f.write(','.join(row + [str(valid)]) + '\n')
```

Comment: set the input file for the second as the output of the first?

Comment: By doing that wouldn't I still have two output files?  I'd like to only have 1 output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let put your code as function of filenames:

```
def first_code(file_in, file_out):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_in, ... )
    ...
    df.to_csv(file_out, ...)

def second_code(file_in, file_out):
    with open(file_in, 'r') as f:
        ...
    ....

    with open(file_out, 'w') as f:
        ...
```

Your solution can then be:

```
first_code('data5.csv', 'output.csv')
second_code('output.csv', 'output.csv')
```

Hope it helps

---

Note that there is not problem reading and writing in the same file. Be sure that the file is previously closed to avoid side effect. This is implicitly done by using `with`, which is a good practice

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, change `data5.csv` which is the first input to the second code to `output.csv`. and make sure that the file1.py and file2.py are in the same directory. so your modified code in a single file will be as follows:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("data5.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
 df = df.resample('1min').mean()
 df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
 df.to_csv("output.csv", na_rep='NaN')

 with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
     rows = [row.split(',') for row in f]
     rows = [[cell.strip() for cell in row if cell] for row in rows]

 def isValidRow(row):
     return float(row[5]) <= 900 or all(float(val) > 7 for val in row[1:4])

 header, rows = rows[0], rows[1:]
 validRows = list(map(isValidRow, rows))

 with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
     f.write(','.join(header + ['IsValid']) + '\n')
     for row, valid in zip(rows, validRows):
         f.write(','.join(row + [str(valid)]) + '\n')
```